# pandas DataFrame pivoting issue

Tags: python, pandas

I've got some radar data that's in a bit of an odd format, and I can't figure out how to correctly pivot it using the pandas library.

My data:

```
    speed   time
loc     
A    63  0000
B    61  0000
C    63  0000
D    65  0000
A    73  0005
B    71  0005
C    73  0005
D    75  0005
```

I'd like to turn that into a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
    0000    0005
loc     
A    63     73
B    61     71
C    63     73
D    65     75
```

I've done a lot of fiddling around but can't seem to get the syntax correct.  Can anyone please help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the pivot method here:

```
In [71]: df
Out[71]: 
     speed  time
loc             
A       63     0
B       61     0
C       63     0
D       65     0
A       73     5
B       71     5
C       73     5
D       75     5

In [72]: df.reset_index().pivot('loc', 'time', 'speed')
Out[72]: 
time   0   5
loc         
A     63  73
B     61  71
C     63  73
D     65  75
```

Comment: I get a result of "ReshapeError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape".  Some of my locations are strings with spaces in them, could that be related?

Comment: Ye. Doesn't work for me either. I get `ReshapeError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape` too.

Comment: I'm on python 2.6.8, pandas 0.8.0.

Comment: Hey, sorry guys, did you try updating? It works on master now. I vaguely remember us having put in fixes for reshaping operations after 0.8.0 so if you just get the latest it should work fine.

Comment: Using the stable version, @ChangShe.  Will wait for the release of the next stable version before upgrading.  Guess this will work then. Good tip nonetheless. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your data source is in a csv file,

```
from pandas.io.parsers import read_csv
df = read_csv("radar_data.csv")

df  # shows what is in df

       loc  speed  time
0    A     63     0
1    B     61     0
2    C     63     0
3    D     65     0
4    A     73     5
5    B     73     5
6    C     75     5
7    D     75     5
8    A     67     0
9    B     68     0
10   C     68     0
11   D     70     0
```

Note that I did not set `loc` as the index yet so it uses an autoincrement integer index.

```
panel = df.set_index(['loc', 'time']).sortlevel(0).to_panel()
```

However, if your data frame is already using `loc` as the index, we will need to append the `time` column into it so that we have a loc-time hierarchal index. This can be done using the new `append` option in the `set_index` method.  Like this:-

```
panel = df.set_index(['time'], append=True).sortlevel(0).to_panel()
```

In either case, we should arrive at this scenario:-

```
panel  # shows what panel is

<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 1 (items) x 4 (major) x 2 (minor)
Items: speed to speed
Major axis: A to D
Minor axis: 0 to 5

panel["speed"]  # <--- This is what you are looking for.


time   0   5
loc         
A     63  67
B     73  61
C     68  73
D     63  68
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That is great, thanks!  My mistake was in not using the sortlevel().to_panel() call.  Reading up on that section of the pandas docs now... Thanks again!

Comment: Welcome. Glad it helps! Notice that for your dataframe, you do not have the autoincrement index. So I edited my answer to suggest that you use the `append=True` option while adding 'time' into your existing 'loc' index.

Comment: If I wanted to get a Series object of all the speeds for a given location, what does the syntax look like?  IE, how can I retrieve a row from the panel?

Comment: `df_by_speed = panel["speed"]` gives you the result for the original question. Now to extract a specific Series by the `loc`, since `loc` is an index in `df_by_speed`, it is as simple as `df_by_speed.ix['A']`  where A is the location name.